# SQL - How to sort rows relative to each other?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table of tasks to be performed. Each task can have one dependency, represented by a column, `dep`. The column forms a FK with the `id` column of the same table. The column is nullable, so a task could have no dependency. I want to be able to sort a list of tasks such that a task will always appear after another task that it depends on.

So, with an example like this:

```
id | name | dep
----------------
1  | A    | NULL
2  | B    | 1
3  | C    | 1
4  | D    | 2
```

Valid orderings would be `A,B,C,D`, `A,C,B,D`, and `A,C,D,B`. This is technically a *partial* ordering. The position of `B` relative to `C` is unimportant. What matters is that 'A' comes before both 'B' and 'C', and 'B' comes before 'D'.

If I were doing something like this in C#, I would probabl create a class that implements the `IComparator<T>` interface, and return `1` or `-1` depending on the object's relationship to each other. But it seems that  SQL's `ORDER BY` clause doesn't allow something like that.

**In standard SQL, how can I sort rows relative to each other, based on a FK relationship?**

---

**UPDATE:**
I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy (`Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1` and `SQLAlchemy==0.9.9`) to connect to the database. For testing I'm using an in-memory sqlite db (version `3.19.3`), and in production I use MySQL 5.6.

I had hoped to avoid CTE's, because I'm unfamiliar with them, and because my version of MySQL doesn't support them.

My DDL would look something like this (MySQL dialect):

```
CREATE TABLE `task` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dep` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id),
  CONSTRAINT `task_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dep`) REFERENCES `task` (`id`)
);
```

My original plan was to sort the tasks like so:

```
SELECT name FROM task JOIN task AS t2 ON (t2.id = task.dep) ORDER BY (???);
```

But I suspect that isn't possible.

Comment: This requires a recursive CTE in most SQL dialects. What database are you using?

Comment: The requirement here is recursive in nature. Your assumption that `IComparator<T>` would work here is wrong (feel free to try - with a large enough input). A "standard" sorting algorithm usually relies on being able to independently compare 2 elements, but that is not the case here

Comment: Please update your question with DDL, input data, and expected output. If you are referencing multiple tables include these as well (*you mentioned FK relationship*). Also tag the database you are using in your question.

Comment: @Amit I think you're right. I was imagining something like this: https://gist.github.com/izrik/83317f927c2e86d5c13d2a5483f879ed 
The problem with this is that unrelated tasks would then be considered "equal", which would probably make a mess of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: This was written for Microsoft SQL Server, which may not be transferrable to the DBMS OP is using. I'll leave it here for reference.

---

While we're waiting for you to update with which DBMS you're using, I'll toss this into the ring. It uses a recursive CTE as the commenters have pointed out to establish the level (ultimately our sort order) each task lives at based on the relationship to its parent. I altered your input data a little to show that is correctly sorts, since yours is already in the ideal order.

```
WITH Test(id, name, dep) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'A', NULL UNION
    SELECT 2, 'B', 4 UNION
    SELECT 3, 'C', 2 UNION
    SELECT 4, 'D', 1 
)
, RecursiveCTE AS
(
  SELECT id, name, dep, 0 AS level
  FROM Test
  WHERE dep IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i.id, i.name, i.dep, level + i.id
  FROM Test i
  INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE c ON c.id = i.dep
)
SELECT id, name, dep
FROM RecursiveCTE
ORDER BY level;
```

Output:

```
id name dep
-- ---- ----
1  A    NULL
4  D    1
2  B    4
3  C    2
```

Comment: I'll try this out. I'm not familiar with CTE's, so there will likely be a learning curve.

Comment: @Cory That worked for me. I even tried it with other sample data sets and got the correct ordering. Just out of curiosity, when you calculate the level, why do you use `level + i.id` instead of `level + 1`? The ordering should not rely on the id value, should it?

Comment: You could use `+ 1` for your purposes; `+ i.id` is merely a safety check to ensure the ranking is based on the `id`.